# BO Reports: have a formula produce a null

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I need to have a formula produce a null in some cases, numeric in others.  Then I'll use number formatting to present accordingly.  Something like this:

```
=If(Count([Product Id]) = 1) Then null Else [Amount]
```

Unfortunately `null` is not a recognised keyword.  I've tried `nil` and `nothing` also (clutching at straws).

Is it possible?

(Business Objects 12 - Web editor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try just `=If(Count([Product Id]) <> 1) Then [Amount]`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding output "null", one of the tricks I've used for other types is to have an empty formula, and refer to the formula when you need a NULL.

```
@IsNull
// This formula is here just to represent a NULL -- it has no content
```

Then refer to this as a result in your other formula.

```
@MyRealFormula
If(Count([Product Id]) = 1) Then @IsNull Else [Amount]
```

I don't remember wx this works for NUMBER, but it helps w/ other types.